# On weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I have the following Statement to prove

Let $C$ be a closed, bounded and convex subset of a $\mathbb{K}$-Vectorspace $X$. Define a Support function $S_C:X^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,   $f\rightarrow sup_{x\in C}f(x)$

To show is now:

i) $\forall y\in X:y\in C\iff \forall f\in X^*: f(y)\leq S_C(f)$

ii) $(x_n)_n\subset C$, $(x_n)_n\rightarrow  x\in X$ weakly $\Rightarrow x\in C$

iii) Let detine the function $d_C: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R_\geq 0}, y\rightarrow d_C(y)= inf_{x\in C}||x-y||$. If X is reflexive $\Rightarrow \forall y\in X$ there exists the infimum.

I started the fist point proving this direction "$\Rightarrow$" but i've doubts obout the other one. I dont'see the argument that gives the conclusion.

At the second point I was thinking on a contradiction-proof trying to assume $\notin C$. Then since the sequence is weak convergent, I know that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x) \forall f\in X^*$ but then I don't know how to procede..

Any tips would be helpful. thanks

Comment: What did you use to proof this? Did you use Hahn-Banach's theorem?

Comment: No actually I did not used it. I just tried it directly in one direction and seems to work but not in the opposite one... sorry I did not notice that I forgot to write it. Of course yes weak converge was meant. No never heard this lemma

Comment: The second statement means that convex closed sets are weakly closed. This is usually shown with  the separations theorem of convex sets which looks like youf first statement. So you should try to find the contradiction with $i)$. The first statement is usually proven with Hahn-Banach's theorem.

Comment: ok... but using this theorem how can I conclude that $\forall y\in X:y\in C$? Apllying the THM I know that there is an extension of f on the whole X but what I won now?

Comment: What should work for $i)$ could be the following idea. We need to show that for any $y\not\in C$ there is a functional $f\in X*$ such that $f(y)>S_C(f)$. Since $f$ is continuous bounded linear functional, we see that the $\sup f(x)$ must be bounded by a number $F$. The Hahn Banach theorem can provide for any vector $y$ a functional such that $f(y) > F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Obviously, $y \in C$ implies $f(y) \leq S_C(f)$ for any $f \in X^{\ast}$. Now we prove that whenever $y \notin C$ we can define $g \in X^{\ast}$ such that $g(y)> S_C(g)$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $0 \in C$. As $C$ is closed, we know that $d:=d(y,C)>0$. Now we define the open blow-up of $C$ by $$C_d := C+B(0,d/2) := \{x; x=c+b, c \in C, b \in B(0,d/2)\}.$$ Note that $C_d$ is a convex and absorbing set such that $d(x,C_d) \geq d/2$. In particular, the Minkowski functional $$p_{C_d}(x) := \inf\{\lambda \in (0,\infty); x \in \lambda C_d\}$$ is a sublinear function satisfying $p_{C_d}(y)>1$. Moreover, as $B(0,d/2) \subseteq C_d$, it is not difficult to see that $$p_{C_d}(x) \leq 4\frac{\|x\|}{d}, \qquad x \in X \tag{1} $$ Now we set $f: \text{lin}\{y\} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(\lambda y) := \lambda \cdot p_{C_d}(y)$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $g:X \to \mathbb{R}$ linear such that $$g(x) \leq p_{C_d}(x), \qquad x \in X \tag{2}$$ and $g(y)=p_{C_d}(y)$. In particular, we see that $$g(x) \leq p_{C_d}(x) \leq 1 < p_{C_d}(y)=g(y)$$ for any $x \in C$ and $g \in X^{\ast}$ by $(1)$ and $(2)$. This finishes the proof. (If you know the supporting hyperplane theorem, the proof is much more easier.)
2. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq C$ such that $x_n \to x$ weakly. By (i), we have $$x \in C \Leftrightarrow \forall f \in X^{\ast}: f(x) \leq S_C(f).$$ Now, as $x_n \to x$ weakly, we know that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \leq S_C(f).$$
3. Since $X$ is reflexive, the unit ball in $X$ is weakly compact. By definition, we can choose a sequence $(x_n)_n \subseteq C$ such that $\|y-x_n\| \to d_C(y)$. Show that $(x_n)$ admits a weakly convergent subsequence and that the limit $x \in C$ satisfies $d(y,C) = \|x-y\|$.

Comment: May I ask two things? (1) What does absorbing mean in this context? (2) From where do we know that the linear function $g$ is indeed in $X^*$?

Comment: @Thorben $C$ is absorbing iff for any $x \in X$ there exists $\lambda_0>0$ such that $x \in \lambda C$ for any $|\lambda| \geq \lambda_0$. (In fact, there was a mistake in my proof; hopefully, is is correct now.)

Comment: Ah ok, was not sure if it was wrong. I thought that I am just to slow to see that continuity of $g(x)$ follows trivially somewhere.